# Scrolling to reach a Dom Object Position and then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i was working on a galery where when the user scrolls and reaches a thumb certain background action occurs. 
Now  did this coding and i am able to get the result but somehow i am confused as it only works one time and then when i again scroll to that position it does nothing.
I am using alert boxes to reach 5th and 7th thumb and it only shows message once. 
I am using something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


        // Thumb 1
        var thumb4Target = $("#myImg1").offset().top;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= thumb4Target) {
                alert('1nd Image Position Obtained');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 0);

        //Thumb 2
        var thumb4Target2 = $("#myImg2").offset().top;

        var interval2 = setInterval(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= thumb4Target2) {
                alert('2nd Image Position Obtained');
                clearInterval(interval2);
            }
        }, 0);

    });
```

check this Fiddle
[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/JGrWC/)

***Please tell me where i am doing wrong.Thanks.***

Comment: Instead of using two intervals of 0, better would be to use onscroll event on window object. And ya, it works only once for each element because you are clearing interval

Comment: Can you do me a Fiddle Please?

Comment: Wait, someone less lazy than you and me will provide you a correct answer soon, maybe...

Comment: I am quite a newbie!!! not lazy!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`scroll`**](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event instead of `interval`. [**LIVE DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/JGrWC/1/) Or **[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/JGrWC/3/)**

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
   var thumb4Target = $("#myImg1").offset().top; 
   var thumb4Target2 = $("#myImg2").offset().top;

   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= thumb4Target) {
       alert('1nd Image Position Obtained');
   }
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= thumb4Target2) {
       alert('2nd Image Position Obtained');
   }
});
```

Comment: Hey this works but it keeps alerting till next thumb is on position.

Comment: @MarcAndre Instead of using `>=` see using '===' And better would be to put `thumb4Target` and `thumb4Target 2` outside scroll handler

Comment: @Wolff Please help me man. i am a newbie.. please create a fiddle.

Comment: @MarcAndre ok, i'll check

Comment: @MarcAndre It's because of your if statement. If you use `==` instead of `>=` it wont help to solve the problem cause the chance of that two values become equal in the condition is very low. You should be specific that what exactly you want to do. It's another demo with another if condition: [scroll it slowly](http://jsfiddle.net/JGrWC/3/)

Comment: @Siamak.A.M true tested it, here another demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JGrWC/4/  But depending what you are looking for. There is a great plugin for this kind of thing, called waypoints.js, here: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: @Siamak.A.M But why are you using +10 and -10 in the example?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M And why should be it scrolled slowly?thanks

Comment: @MarcAndre 10 is a number you can change it to 5 or any number you like. It depends on how sensitive you want it be. I give you an example. Think the item position is 100px from top. when you scroll slowly the scrollTop() returns numbers like this. [2,4,6,...,100,...,600] so it would be equal when it's on 100 and it goes through if. But if you scroll fast the scrollTop() returns numbers like this [30,60,90,120,150,...,600]. And as you see it's not equal to the element position so it never goes through if. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M its very sensitive.It's sometimes skipping. can you help me fix that?

Comment: @MarcAndre just increase the number use 20 or 30 or ... instead of 10 and choose the best fit number.